# R: polygon does not align with curves

Tags: r, plot

I made the plot below in R. The edges of the polygon should align with the two curves as they are plotted using the same vectors. Yet, the polygon is slightly higher on the Y-axis relative to the curves. I cannot figure out why.

How do I get the outer edges of the polygon to align with the two curves?

Similarly, why does the polygon not extend all the way too the right end of the two curves? The curves are somewhat loner than the polygon.

I realize that I can plot the polygon with borders and not plot the two lines. That does not solve the underlying problem. Both the polygon and the two curves are plotted using the `upper` and `lower` vectors so I think they should align exactly. They do not.

```
lower <- qchisq(0.05,0:100)
upper <- qchisq(0.95,0:100)
df <- (0:100)

plot(df,upper, type='n', axes=F)
polygon(c(0,df,rev(df)), c(0,upper,rev(lower)), col='grey75',border=NA)
axis(1,pos=0)
axis(2,pos=0, las=1)
lines(upper, col='black')
lines(lower,col='black')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lines` assumes the index is `1:length(x)` (where `x` is the input) when you don't specify a second argument.

But in your case it's `0:100`. Add `df` as the first argument to `lines`:

```
lines(df, upper, col='black')
lines(df, lower, col='black')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something simple but it never registered that the curves were shifted to the right by 1.